# Conditionally rendering JSX in multiple places

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to conditionally render JSX in multiple instances of a component simultaneously. The idea is to add a div that underlines the currently active title. There should always be one active title per instance of the component, indicated like this:

[desired output here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QCT04.png)

I've tried re-working several ways but always end with only one active title in total, across all sections.

It seems like there are issues with how I'm updating activeTenses. I'm updating based on the previous version but when I update one key / value pair, the other is overwritten and is set back to its initial state of "present".

Parent component:

```
export default function VerbPage() {
  let params = useParams();

  return (
    <>
      <Nav />
      <Header verb={params.verb} />
      <TenseGroup tenseSection="indicative" tenses={["Present", "Preterite", "Imperfect", "Conditional", "Future"]}>Present Indicative</TenseGroup>
      <TenseGroup tenseSection="subjunctive" tenses={["Present", "Imperfect", "Future"]}>Subjunctive</TenseGroup>
    </>
  );
}
```

Child component:

```
export default function TenseGroup({ children, tenses, tenseSection }) {
  const [activeTenses, setActiveTenses] = useState({
    indicative: "present",
    subjunctive: "present"
  });

  function handleTensesClick(tense) {
    setActiveTenses((prevTense) => {
      return {
        ...prevTense,
        [tenseSection]: tense
      }
    });
  }

  return (
    <section>
      <div>{children}</div>
      <ul>
      {tenses.map((tense) => (
        <li key={tense}>
          <div onClick={() => handleTensesClick(tense.toLowerCase())}>{tense}</div>
          {activeTenses[tenseSection] === tense.toLowerCase() && (
            <motion.div className={classes["tense__underline"]} layoutId="animate-tense"></motion.div>
          )}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
    </section>
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue lays in the fact that you have the same layoutId in both components. Giving different motion elements the same layoutId property lets you animate between them.

The state property is getting set properly. The condition `activeTenses[tenseSection] === tense.toLowerCase()` is satisfied. However motion animates them both together.

So simply modify the layoutId to include your tenseSection name and it should work.

```
<motion.div className={classes["tense__underline"]}
            layoutId={`animate-tense-${tenseSection}`}>
</motion.div>
```

However since you do not actually store the state in a context, there is no reason to keep the state as an object if each instance of TenseGroup only renders one tenseSection. So you could simplify your state like so:

```js
const TenseGroup: React.FC<PropsWithChildren<{tenses: Array<string>, tenseSection: string}>> = ({ children, tenses, tenseSection  }) => {
    const [activeTense, setActiveTense] = useState<string>("present");

    return (
        <section>
            <div>{children}</div>
            <ul>
                {tenses.map((tense) => (
                    <li key={tense}>
                        <div onClick={() => setActiveTense(tense.toLowerCase())}>{tense}</div>
                        {activeTense === tense.toLowerCase() && (
                            <motion.div className={classes["tense__underline"]} layoutId={`animate-tense-${tenseSection}`}>test</motion.div>
                        )}
                    </li>
                ))}
            </ul>
        </section>
    )
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the thorough explanation, amending layoutId fixed everything